# In MySql how do I get all rows that have a date of less than or equal to today at 5 am UTC time?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySql DB that consists of a table that holds all my data. I need to retrieve only those rows that have a startup_date that is less than or equal to today at 5 am UTC time. I tried looking up but it's kind of confusing. Can someone provide me a good, clean way of doing this?

My table is as follows:

---

```
  tbl_MyData
  ***********
  id      name       city        startup_date
  1      test1      New York    2020-01-10 18:19:30
  2      test2      Houston     2019-01-30 05:00:00
  3      test3      Chicago     2020-02-09 05:00:00
```

From the above data, my query should return ONLY row id number 2, since that is the only row that satisfies my criteria of startup_date being less than or equal to today at 5 am. Also, I'm not sure if I need to have any kind of UTC functions, since I'm not sure how mysql stores it's date time data.

Comment: Everything you need to know about MySQL data and time but weren't afraid to ask - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT t.* FROM mytable WHERE t.startup_date <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 HOUR)
```

The `CURDATE()` function returns the current date without time (hence today at midnight), and the `DATE_ADD()` function adds 5 hours to it.

Comment: GMB - I'm a bit confused - why the DateAdd? I need to take the existing date time stamp in the row and make sure that it is less than or equal (<=) today at 5 a.m. How will your query achieve that.

Comment: @RogerDodger : this expression : `DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 HOUR)` actually means : today at 5 AM. See [this fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xi4twz5xsrCeFn8bCFBmYM/0)

Answer (score 1):

What SELECT statement have you tried also what are the data types for the table? If startup-date is a date type in MySQL then it should just be

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_MyData WHERE startup_date<=(whatever the value needs to be)
```